# Filtering users in socket.io and seeing who is online

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, socket.io

While implementing socket.io on my server, I ran into some problems and eventually fixed them. The code below is fired on the connection event of socket.io:

```
var newarray = []; //a new array
data.map(function(inde) { //data is an array which contains the data of the user's acc_id and some more information, 
    newarray.push({
        enc: inde.fjbngh, //encrypted acc_id
        hmac: inde.asdty2 //hmac
    })
});
var users = []; // a new array which will contain the decrypted acc_id's
newarray.forEach(function(llol) {
    var dec = _SOME_DECRYPTION_FUNCTION_WITH_HMAC;
    users.push(dec); // decrypted acc_id stored in the array
})
uniq = [...new Set(users)]; // To get one values out of any unique values as with every user, i'm getting the logged in user's id, so this code whole code is executed once (not in a foreach loop)
var idst = {}; // a new object
idst['socket_id'] = socket.id;
idst['acc_id'] = Number(uniq[0]);
ids.push(idst);// ids is the main global array which contains the socket_id with a unique acc_id.
```

The job of the code above is to procure the `acc_id` of the logged in user and store it in a global array, by which we can know if a user is online or not.

This code fires up on the connection event of socket.io, and the reason why I'm storing `acc_id` with `socket_id` is that, whenever a user opens a new tab, web sockets gets 2 unique clients from the same browser but different tabs, so I saved it with an `acc_id`to avoid multiple clients from the same browser.

The reason for all the filtering is because, it's the connection event and with that, I'm sending all the `acc_id`(s) of the users, the logged in user needs to chat. I have settled that procedure.

Example of the data array object:

```
[{ id_of_another_user:'xx', hmac:'xx', id_of_logged_in_user:'xx', hmac:'xx'}]
```

On disconnection, the user is removed from the `ids` array. My question is, does this code perform its job in the most efficient way possible?

I have another doubt that might make this question broad, so I'll ask it later.